# Combo Box Record Issue

Tags: ms-access

I am just learning database design and using Access for a class project.  I've created a form to track case notes, and I'm having an issue.  I want to select a Name in a combo box, then above it select the date combo box that will list all of the notes created for that person, displayed by their dates.  Simply click on the date, and the note appears in the Note field below.  It's meant to be a read-only form so you can't edit the created notes, just view them.

Well it works fine, but when I have multiple notes that were created on the same day, you can only select the first note from that day, not the subsequent notes from the same day.  Clicking on them does nothing, and the Note field continues to display the first days record.  Even clicking the Date combo box and the later notes in the same day still brings up the first note of the day.  Weirdly though, clicking on the drop-down arrow in the date combo-box and then using the arrow keys on the keyboard cycle through the dates just fine though.  It just doesn't work when using a trackpad/mouse.  What gives?

Thanks!!!
[image]

Comment: Does the note date combobox RowSource include the CaseNoteID? What is the RecordSource for the form?

Comment: The reason the keyboard works is that this cycles through records in the recordset of the form (nothing to do with the Date drop-down). As @June7 alluded to, you should include the CaseNoteID as a hidden field in the Date drop-down alongside the date (and probably an additional field to help the user differentiate notes on the same date) and then use that ID in your form filter.

Comment: Andrew, I added CaseNoteID as a hidden field int he Date drop-down.  The problem still persists.  Are you saying I should then create a form filter using CaseNoteID?

Comment: Sorry June7, the Raw Source is SELECT CaseNote.Date, CaseNote.Note, Tenant.TenantID, CaseNote.Time FROM Tenant INNER JOIN CaseNote ON Tenant.TenantID = CaseNote.TenantID WHERE (((Tenant.TenantID)=[Forms]![ArchiveCaseNote]![cboName]));

Comment: What's weird though, and I don't understand, is that I can select multiple records with no problem from the drop down combo box.  The issue is only when I have multiple records with the same date.

Comment: Figured it out in case others have the same issue.  Dumb error on my part.  I had to change the event to AfterUpdate, not BeforeUpdate.  Fixed my problem lol.  NooBish of me...